# Fragment communication in a TabLayout activity

Tags: java, android

I have android project that have three tabs. in one of 3 tabs has a ListView of different activities in which if that item clicked should come direct to assigned fragment
those tabs are TABA TABB TABC on TABB that has list of activities in which if someone click should direct to another fragment and activities containing these tabs should not be shown

I tried to call those fragmenttransaction inside istView.setOnItemClickListener but no any thing change

In tabs TABB 
here are the code

```
public class Activities extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
    public Activities() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activities, container, false);

        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("listview_title", ListTitle[i]);
            hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(ListImage[i]));
            aList.add(hm);
        }
        String [] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title"};
        int [] to = {R.id.listview_image, R.id.listview_item_title};

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),aList,
                R.layout.activity_listview, from, to);
        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
               FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//R.id.container is on activity_main.xml
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FileDownloadFragment());
                transaction.commit();



            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <!--!app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

   <!-- <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.jeliel.easycontrol.activities.Activities">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm expecting this when item clicked on ListView should bring me on fragment called FileDownloadFragment()